# "Плавающая" кнопка

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать кнопку "онлайн-консультант" так, чтобы эта кнопка всегда находилась слева и не проматывалась вместе со страницей, а как бы "плавала" за окном или просто находилась на фиксированном месте (x:1 y:1).

Comment: Это означает поверх всех имеющихся окон 999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

html:

```
<div class="fixed_button">button</div>
```

css:

```
.fixed_button{
  position:fixed; /*задаём тип позиции, в нашем случае - фиксированная*/
  top:100px;      /* отступ сверху*/
  left:0px;       /* отступ слева*/
  width:100px;    /* ширина кнопки*/
  height:35px;    /* высота кнопки*/
  z-index:999;    /*позиция относительно дальности*/
}
```

Comment: Я пробовал, но IE почему-то показывает ее неправильно. Причем не только у меня... Chrome и Firefox - отлично, а IE просто вставляет рисунок в том месте, где написан код... Что еще посоветуете?

Comment: Стоп, а что за "позиция относительно дальности"... я ее не писал... Что это означает?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deamondz/D2F79/